# Como mover registros desde Routed Zone publica a privada

Tags: dns

Acudo a todos para ver si me pueden dar una mano con un proyecto en el que me encuentro atrasado, y necesito resolverlo lo antes posible.

El mismo consiste en mover los registros del dominio publico a privado.

Por ejemplo yo cuento con los siguiente registros dentro del dominio publico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A su vez cuento con un dominio privado.

Esto necesitando encontrar un metodo con un script que me permirta mover los registros publicos a privados. Estaba pensando en un script en Python, pero escucho sugerencias.

Alguien me podra dejar algún ejemplo en Python o algún otro leguanje que me permita realizar esto?

Comment: Sería de gran ayuda saber el nombre del producto. Con eso podría buscar el manual, estudiarlo y darte respuesta.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/535631/how-to-export-a-hosted-zone-in-aws-route-53

Comment: El producto es de AWS route 53 se llama. En ese servicio podes crear dominios publicos y privados.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿ Me podrán mostrar como realizar un script en python que me permita mover registros de DNS Route 53 en AWS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/570170/me-podr%c3%a1n-mostrar-como-realizar-un-script-en-python-que-me-permita-mover-regis)

Comment: @josealcaraz recomiendo leas [ask]